# Good way to iterate through this table?

Tags: sql-server

I have table like this:

```
ID Name Date StartTime EndTime SomeOtherID
1 Mark 2011-11-25 15:00 17:00 1
1 Tom  2011-11-26 17:00 19:00 1
1 Jack 2011-11-27 20:00 22:00 1
```

I need to do this

```
select * from other table 
Where ID=1
AND( 
(Date = 2011/12/25 and time between 15:00 and 17:00) 
OR (Date =2011/12/26 and time between 17:00 and 19:00)
OR (Date =2011/12/27 and time between 19:00 and 21:00)
)
```

I need to do this for every row where SomeOtherID =1, for Unknown number of rows (may be 2, may be 30, so I can't use fixed number of parameters).

Hope this question is understandable.

Comment: Can you show us some sample data to understand what you have, and can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do to each row when you iterate through the table??

Comment: Could you show a second set of rows from the first table?? So the names really aren't relevant at all - right? The `ID = 1` just basically defines which date and time ranges you have in your second query, correct??

Comment: And do you need to do this in T-SQL alone, or could you use a front-end programming language (like C#, Ruby or something) ?? To do this in T-SQL alone is quite a messy affair, I'm afraid..... you basically need to create dynamic SQL based on your first query, and execute it

Comment: I'd like to write stored procedure which I'd call from ASP.NET. And Sergei's idea is very helpful. I'd go for cursor or something that complicate, but this is fine. Thank you, and thanks to others who wanted to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM other_table ot
INNER JOIN (SELECT Date, StartTime, EndTime 
            FROM first_table
            WHERE SomeOtherID = 1
           ) ft ON ot.Date = ft.Date AND ot.Time BETWEEN (ft.StartTime, ft.EndTime)
WHERE ID=1;
```

Comment: Table represented in my question have times and dates, and other table have values that should be selected where time is between StartTime and EndTime in first table, where SomeOtherID in first table is (some value)

Comment: I didn't understand this at all. Why there's only one table mentioned in the question?

Comment: Let say that for ID=1 in mentioned table we have
Date = 2011/12/25 StartTime = 14:00 EndTime=16:00
Date = 2011/12/26 StartTime = 15:00 EndTime=17:00
Date = 2011/12/27 StartTime = 19:00 EndTime=20:00

I should select * from other table 
where (Date = 2011/12/27 and time between 19:00 and 20:00)
OR (Date =2011/12/26 and time between 15:00 and 17:00)

etc.

Comment: Still hard to understand. Edit the question to better explain what you want.

Comment: Edited. Please ask if still not understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * 
from SomeTable 
where Time between StartTime and EndTime 
and Date = Date
AND SomeOtherID = 1
```